# Search data with dao and store in model. How i access data stored in model?

Tags: java, dao

Following some tutorials i made a connection to database through java:

DBConnect.java

```
public class DBConnect {
public Connection jdbcConnection;

public void connect() throws SQLException{
    if(jdbcConnection == null || jdbcConnection.isClosed()) {
        try {
            Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e);
        }
        jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUser, jdbcPass);
    }
}

public void disconnect() throws SQLException{
    if(jdbcConnection != null || !jdbcConnection.isClosed()){
        jdbcConnection.close();
    }
}
}
```

a User.java   (user model)

```
package model;

public class User {
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String registeredDate;
private String lastUpdate;
private int active;

public User(String name, String email, String password){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(int id, String name, String email, String password, int active){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.active = active;
}

public User(int id, String name, String email, String password, String registeredDate, String lastUpdate, int active){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.registeredDate = registeredDate;
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    this.active = active;
}

public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}

public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}

public String getRegisteredDate(){
    return this.registeredDate;
}

public String getLastUpdate(){
    return this.lastUpdate;
}

public void setActive(int active){
    this.active = active;
}

public int getActive(){
    return this.active;
}

}
```

And user.java (user dao)

```
package dao;

import model.User;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Users extends DBConnect{

public User findOne(int id) throws SQLException {
    User user = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = ?";

        connect();
        PreparedStatement stmt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            String password = rs.getString("password");
            String registeredDate = rs.getString("registered_date");
            String lastUpdate = rs.getString("last_update");
            int active = rs.getInt("active");

            user = new User(id, name, email, password, registeredDate, lastUpdate, active);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        disconnect();

        return user;
}

public List<User> findAll() throws SQLException{
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY ID ASC";

    connect();
    Statement stmt = jdbcConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    while(rs.next()){
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String password = rs.getString("password");
        String registeredDate = rs.getString("registered_date");
        String lastUpdate = rs.getString("last_update");
        int active = rs.getInt("active");

        User user = new User(id, name, email ,password, registeredDate, lastUpdate, active);
        users.add(user);
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    disconnect();

    return users;
}


}
```

My main issue is that i am trying to call findOne and findAll methods and access each parameter individually. I am not understanding how i can do this properly, if each response is wrapped in User (model) class.

I tried in this way:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException{
    Users getAll = new Users();
    ArrayList<User> test = getAll.findOne(1);
    System.out.println(test.name);


}
}
```

I am aware that i am doing it wrong, but how can i access my results from user ?
Thank you.

Comment: do you mean, accessing each parameter from findAll individually through model?

Comment: @RujalShrestha Yes, that's what i want. Sorry for my lack of english.

Comment: Users getAll = new Users();
    ArrayList<User> test = getAll.findAll();
    for(User usr: test){System.out.println(usr.toString();)}


above is the ans :) .. you can do it by 'for loop'